# Book about a war against evolved rats attacking Earth with bioweapons that kill women

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been trying to recall a sci-fi book I read;  the key elements I recall is that only men were in space as women were kept on Earth after a bio-attack that killed most women.

Along the way the young spacefarers spend a lot of time polishing brightwork and the humans help a squid-like race when they are honored with their images over a hatching pond.

The protagonists in the book are a race of rat-like creatures that were taken from Earth a long time ago and evolved on another world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[To Honor You Call Us](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18318651-to-honor-you-call-us)*** (2012) by H. Paul Honsinger...? It's the first book in the *[Man of War](https://www.goodreads.com/series/106083-man-of-war)* series.

From a Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2347128879):

> ***Man of War* is set roughly three centuries into the future and humanity, utilizing the 'jump drive', quickly colonized many planets and systems.** Originally under the 'Terran Federation', the political system eventually collapsed, leaving several 'pockets' of independent human 'empires'.
>
> Humanity also discovered several alien species, most of which are higher on the tech chain, but one became of special interest-- the Krag. It seems **roughly 11 million years ago, some alien power transported a swath of flora and fauna from Earth and terriformed another planet; eventually, the species that became dominant and space-faring where the Krag. The Krag are humanoid, but trace their ancestors to rats rather than monkeys. For some bizarre religious rationale, the Krag have vowed to wipe out humanity** and for the last 30 years have been at war with the Terran Union, which comprises about 500 of the 600 planets and systems colonized by humanity. It is total war and the Terran Union is losing slowly.

From another [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/944144018):

> OK, **the Krag are engaged in an acknowledged war of human extermination. As part of that war, they unleashed a terrible plague - the Gynophage. This disease left men largely unaffected, but had a 99% mortality among women.** It spread like crazy and it was only through a Herculean effort that a vaccine was developed. Let's say that it killed 70% of all women and girls.
>
> [...]
>
> **The remaining women are closely guarded and kept out of front line navy deployments.**

Comment: That was the book - Thanks.  It was driving me a little crazy trying to place it.

Comment: @user163231 - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.